# cleaning up nginx default.conf file

Tags: nginx

This is part of my configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass backend;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/s/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;

    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

I have multiple subdomains that I'm running and each one I make I have to copy/paste this huge chunk of code. is there any way i can make this reusable?

Comment: What's in your `fastcgi_params`? Are you sure that it does not have `QUERY_STRING`, `REQUEST_METHOD` and `CONTENT_*` params?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by putting everything except fastcgi_pass and SCRIPT_FILENAME in a separate configuration file.